# NMecabをいれたUnityPackageのエラーについて

Tags: unity3d

Unityのゲーム画面上では問題なくNMecabの品詞わけが行われていたのですが，Buildして作成されたファイルを実行するとNMecabがうまく動作しないためかエラーを出します．
不足情報があったら追加で書きたします．よろしくお願いします．
エラーコードの一部です。

```
TypeLoadException:Could not load type
'System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase'from assembly 'System.
```

Comment: Unityについては詳しくないのですが、エラーの内容があると良いと思います(むしろないと回答できないかも)。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．そうですよね。失礼いたしました

Answer (score 1):

これは、Unity>File>BuildSettings>PlayerSettings>OtherSettingsのApi Compatibility Level を　.NET2.0subset ではなく　.NET2.0　に変更することで解消できることがあります。